# Allowing microphone access(permission) in WebView [Android Studio] [Java]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-permissions

I am currently working on a music tuner that uses html5 and a webview to display the 'application'. I've written the all the permission required in manifest and I think for webview there's another permission required.

I am using this https://jbergknoff.github.io/guitar-tuner/ as a sample redirect page for now

Here's my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.raynordev.projectrosin">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.raynordev.projectrosin.HomeActivity">        

  </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's my .java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView wv;
private String TAG = "HomeActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_INTERNET = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    wv.loadUrl("https://jbergknoff.github.io/guitar-tuner/");
 }
}
```

If require more information from me, please let me know.

Thank you everyone!!

Answer (score 39):

You can use the following code that I copied from http://web.archive.org/web/20160111030837/http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html —

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> MainActivity
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>     private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 101;
>     private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;
>     private PermissionRequest myRequest;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
>         setWebView();
>     }
>
>     private void setWebView() {
>         mBinding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>         mBinding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
>         mBinding.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
>
>         mBinding.webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
>         mBinding.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
>         mBinding.webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
>         mBinding.webViemBinding.webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
>
>
>         mBinding.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
>             @Override
>             public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
>                 myRequest = request;
>
>                 for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
>                     switch (permission) {
>                         case "android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE": {
>                             askForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(),
> ```
>
> Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
> MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
> break;
> }
> }
> }
> }
> });
>
> ```
>         mBinding.webView.loadUrl("<your url");
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onBackPressed() {
>         if (mBinding.webView.canGoBack()) {
>             mBinding.webView.goBack();
>         } else {
>             super.onBackPressed();
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>                                            String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>         switch (requestCode) {
>             case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO: {
>                 Log.d("WebView", "PERMISSION FOR AUDIO");
>                 if (grantResults.length > 0
>                         && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>
>                     // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                     // contacts-related task you need to do.
>                     myRequest.grant(myRequest.getResources());
>                     mBinding.webView.loadUrl("<your url>");
>
>                 } else {
>
>                     // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                     // functionality that depends on this permission.
>                 }
>             }
>             // other 'case' lines to check for other
>             // permissions this app might request
>         }
>     }
>     public void askForPermission(String origin, String permission, int requestCode) {
>         Log.d("WebView", "inside askForPermission for" + origin + "with" + permission);
>
>         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
>                 permission)
>                 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>             // Should we show an explanation?
>             if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
>                     permission)) {
>
>                 // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
>                 // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
>                 // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
>
>                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
>                         new String[]{permission},
>                         requestCode);
>             }
>         } else {
>             myRequest.grant(myRequest.getResources());
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Mainfest.xml:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
> ```
>
> Build.gradle:
>
> ```
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 26
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "myapp.example.com.myapplication"
>         minSdkVersion 21
>         targetSdkVersion 21
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: It might not have any explanation but it's the only the that worked for me.

Comment: `request.getResources()` is not available below api level 19.Do we have any solution?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/> adding to Mainfest.xml is the key to use getUserMedia()

Comment: private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;
mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

Facing Error on these lines

Answer (score 5):

Summarising, you need the following components:

1. The `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission.
2. A `WebChromeClient` and listen to callbacks for `onPermissionRequest`
3. Inside this callback, check for the the resources coming in the `request` object, create a global variable of this `request` object, iterate and look for specific permission inside the `PermissionRequest` class, ex. `PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE` which translates to the `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` permission, check if your app has this permission or not, using any mechanism you wish if not, request, if yes do 4.
4. In the permission callback or if the permission is granted, use the request object to grant the permission ex. `request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE})` and you're good to go.

snippet:

```
webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient(){
            override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
                super.onPermissionRequest(request)

                webkitPermissionRequest = request

                request?.resources?.forEach {
                    when(it){
                        PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE-> {
                            askForWebkitPermission(it, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_AUDIO)
                        }
                        PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE->{
                            askForWebkitPermission(it, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private fun askForWebkitPermission(webkitPermission: String, androidPermission: String, requestCode: Int){
        val context = activity?: return
        if (context.hasPermission(androidPermission)){
            webkitPermissionRequest!!.grant(arrayOf(webkitPermission))
        }else{
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(androidPermission), requestCode)
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Google's sample for the same: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PermissionRequest

Comment: Why do I need to create a global variable for the request? Surely the request is passed "by reference" and could be used directly?

Comment: This is the right answer, some permissions like this need to granted with "webkitPermissionRequest!!.grant(arrayOf(webkitPermission))" too

Answer (score 2):

its problems for reload the webview , after too much research , found this code and create this below code :-

```
 mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                myRequest = request;
                for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                    if (permission.equals("android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE")) {
                        demandForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                    } else {
                        myRequest.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
            super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request);
        }
```

more info in this link **[Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528122/allowed-camera-audio-or-all-other-permissions-on-webview-webrtc-chromium-web)**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your recent experience on this topic, even though the OP was from many years ago. Your contribution continues to make this topic useful and relevant.