# WebRTC Permission Audio Access in Android

Tags: android, permissions, webrtc

I am developing an android application in which I need to internally display the link clicked by the user and grant permission to use a microphone.

I am trying to replicate the behavior of Google Chrome in my Android Webview in my application. [Permission for Audio Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7FQW.png)

But I got stuck on how to implement a pop-up permission that will grant access to use microphone like how the browser does.

Here is a sample website that I need to open internally:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Any idea how to implement this? Or what should I study more?

Comment: Have you tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410311/192373?

Comment: it worked to use a microphone in the webview. i just need to modify it to add pop up permission and ask the user to grant access to record audio. thanks.