# Webview Audio Permission

Tags: android, webview, android-permissions, user-permissions

I want to open a recording audio website in my webview. And when I load, it asks for permission and granted successfully but webview still says permission is not granted. Any solution for that.
It works fine in a new fresh project but not working in an existing project.
 Thanks.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236925/allowing-microphone-accesspermission-in-webview-android-studio-java

Comment: I tried this one bro @Prateek. but it doesn't work.